Reference for the main theorem of genus theory of ideal class group
Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic number field and $\mathrm{Cl}_K$ be the ideal class group of $K$. The main theorem of what we call genus theory is:

$\#{\mathrm{Cl}}_K[2] = 2^{r-1}$ where $r$ is the number of prime
factors of the discriminant of $K$.

But I have never seen this statement in published papers or books. All papers I know cite this result as 'By genus theory'. Could you please tell me the reference for this statement?

Consult Cox's "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$", specifically chapters 3 and 6

You say $K$ is a number field without other restrictions.  Did you intend to have $K$ be a quadratic field?
See Theorem 8 on page 247 in Borevich and Shafarevich's "Number Theory".  When $G$ is a finite abelian group, $\#\{g \in G : g^k = 1\} = \#G/G^k$ for each integer $k$, where $G^k$ is the subgroup of $k$th powers. You are interested in $k = 2$.
See also Prop. 4.8, Prop. 4.9, and Theorem 4.4 in Ono's "An Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory".

Thank you very mich. I intended a imaginary quadratic field K.

When looking at references that cover general quadratic $K$, you may see conditions such as "strict equivalence" or "narrow class group", which involve a potentially finer notion of equivalence than that in the usual class group, where we now care about principal ideals having a totally positive generator or a generator with a positive norm. Such extra conditions are vacuous in the imaginary quadratic case where all nonzero elements have positive norm, but may not be in the real quadratic case, e.g., in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{3}]$ no generator of $(\sqrt{3})$ has a positive norm.
